# How to send mail in powershell based on exception count?

Tags: powershell, email, backup

im trying to set up a Powershell script, which backs up a specific SiteCollection and sends an email afterwards, stating if the backup was successfully or not. 
I'm stuck at the point where I need to check if there was an exception or not.
This is my code so far:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
try
{
$name = "xxxx"
$today = (Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy)
[IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("E:\Backup\SiteCollections\$name\$today")

Backup-SPsite -Identity http://xxxxxxx.xxxxx.de/sites/xxxxxx -Path     E:\Backup\SiteCollections\$name\$today\$name.bak –Force
}
catch
{
 #check for errors
}
#send mail success if no error
#send mail error if exception count is >0
```

At the end of the day my script should have checked whether an exception has occured or not and based on this alter the mail subject  / body.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you change the ErrorVariable of PowerShell cmdlet they'll store error information in `$Error`

So you can just check `$Error.Count` to see if there is any errors

Comment: Sometimes I am just plain stupid. Thank you Per :> Works like a charm.